# codeigniter rest server POST "not allowed", but GET works fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am using codeigniter-restserver by Phil Sturgeon,

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

here is an problem I encountered:

When I do PUT request, everything works, but when I do POST, I got
"500 Internal Server Error"

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
  <p>The action you have requested is not allowed.</p>
</div>
```

my code is the following:

```
function test_post()
{
    $this->response('ok', 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
}

function test_get()
{
    $this->response('ok', 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
}
```

the working GET handelling can be found in the following URL

https://manage.pineconetassel.com/index.php/api/example/test/

NOTE that I allowed https only.

I used hurl.it to test the POST method, and it does not work.

here is the rest.php config:

```
$config['force_https'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_default_format'] = 'json';
$config['rest_status_field_name'] = 'status';
$config['rest_message_field_name'] = 'error';
$config['enable_emulate_request'] = TRUE;
$config['rest_realm'] = 'REST API';
$config['rest_auth'] = false;
$config['auth_source'] = 'ldap';
$config['auth_library_class'] = '';
$config['auth_library_function'] = '';
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('admin' => '1234');
$config['rest_ip_whitelist_enabled'] = false;
$config['rest_ip_whitelist'] = '';
$config['rest_ip_blacklist_enabled'] = false;
$config['rest_ip_blacklist'] = '';
$config['rest_database_group'] = 'default';
$config['rest_keys_table'] = 'keys';
$config['rest_enable_keys'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_key_column'] = 'key';
$config['rest_key_length'] = 40;
$config['rest_key_name'] = 'X-API-KEY';
$config['rest_logs_table'] = 'logs';
$config['rest_enable_logging'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_access_table'] = 'access';
$config['rest_enable_access'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_logs_json_params'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_limits_table'] = 'limits';
$config['rest_enable_limits'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ignore_http_accept'] = FALSE;
$config['rest_ajax_only'] = FALSE;
```

Did I do something wrong or use a wrong way to test the POST or I need to configure something?

Comment: Looks like a cross site issue. Do you have CSRF enabled? You won't be allowed to post via curl, hence the "this action is not allowed" notification.

Comment: your are right, thanks! $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE; in config and the post is allowed. But I think I want to enable it when I am posting sensitive data, do I need to write additional code on the client side to make it work?

Comment: let me add that this api is intended to support an app, so I am not quite sure how I need to do to enforce csrf_protection because the 'session' does not work like in a website.

Comment: Codeigniter does not offer great support for Restful Services, even the 3rd party libraries are questionable. You could maybe use Laravel for your Data Server as it offers a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` in `config/config.php`

Note it is not uder `config/rest.php`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is right. 
But if you don't want to disable `$config['csrf_protection']` in case you need it for web form, you need to exclude the REST API URIs, for example, your REST url starts with `/api/`, simply set

```php
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
   'api/[a-z0-9/_-]+'
);
```

It is also under `config/config.php`. I use regular expression to make it simple.